# pivot index and balanced partitions (Java)

Tags: java

For big-O for quicksort,

what does it mean when pivot index creates balanced partitions.

I know pivot index is the index where the sum of the numbers to the left of the index is equal to the sum of the numbers to the right of the index.

How does it affect the complexity when it creates balanced partitions and when it does not?

Comment: What do you mean by "pivot index is the index where the sum of the numbers to the left of the index is equal to the sum of the numbers to the right of the index"? Are you sure this is quicksort?

Answer (score 0):

In quicksort, the main idea is to recursively partition the array using a pivot.

In the best case, the chosen pivot is one that always divide the array equally into 2. For example, if you have an unsorted array with [1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 7, 5], the pivot that divides the array into two is 4. This is because using this pivot to partition the array, you get [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], with 3 elements on each side of the pivot.

Writing the recurrence relation for this case, you get: `T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(n)` since the n-sized array can now be seen as 2 n/2-sized arrays and it takes O(n) time for the partitioning process. Using the master theorem/some other way to unroll the recurrence, you get O(nlogn) as the runtime for quicksort.

Unfortunately, such an ideal case is not always possible in real life because the pivot you choose may not be such a nice pivot. In general, however, if you pick a random pivot, you will still have a good chance of dividing the array into 2 reasonably sized parts. In particular, if you can achieve a 1:9 split, it can be mathematically proven that the runtime for quicksort will still be O(nlogn). This is called randomized quicksort, and there are many resources online to explain the probabilistic analysis behind it. Here is [one such resource](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s07/www/lecture_notes/lect0123.pdf).